# Combine neighbouring vector squares together to form a large vector shape

Tags: html, algorithm, canvas, vector, 2d

I am building a 2D renderer in HTML Canvas for a large square-based map where terrain can be of different colours, I have simplified how the map will look by setting the colours to be of three random colours like so - however just rendering a grid the size of a 1080p monitor creates 200 squares, and as the player moves these will be updating 30 times a second at a minimum of 30FPS, which is 6,000 translations per second.

An optimization I have thought of is to combine matching coloured neighbouring squares into one big vector as the world loads in. Right now my approach is to follow the perimeter of the boundaries and compare the square within the shape and outside the shape, however I'm finding that I'm having to write code for so many edge cases that it had be wondering if there was a better way I was missing? This is the screenshot I'm using for reference:

[image]

You can see the random three-coloured terrain, a highlighted orange region to make it easier to identify the shape I'm trying to outline and the red square identifying where the cursor is. F states the active tile being compared and the arrow represents the direction the pen is going, I intended for the algorithm to follow the shape clockwise.

Right now, the map is randomly generated each time the browser refreshes and this screenshot just shows one of the generated shapes. If anyone has any ideas they would be massively appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: Your post is apparently mossing some parts. Also, you can just do `ctx.rect(x1, y1, w1, h1); ctx.rect(x2, y2, w1, h2)` and you'd have a single path that encompasses the 2 rectangles.

Comment: *"to be of three random colours like so [...] this screenshot..."*: there is no screenshot.

Comment: Ah that is embarrassing, edited it now 

Comment: Ah thank you Kaiido, that would be so much simpler than all I had in my head, many thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. Browser games update without doing too many shenanigans render wise and some have quite large maps. The screenshot you provided doesn't show anything too huge - you mention 200 squares. Most PCs will render 200 squares without thinking twice about it. Unless you're attempting to build a stroboscope or something.
As a bit of anecdotical evidence - I've once played around with writing a wave simulator that was updating whole screen pixel by pixel AND computing the pixel modifications at once. It worked ok for the most part. 200 squares should be fine.